# cXML parameters on punchOutSetupRequest

Tags: cxml-commercexml

Currently we are implementing cXML punchout system. What should we insert for the identity in the Header?

sample:

```
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="DUNS">
<Identity>65652314</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="DUNS">
<Identity>83528721</Identity>
</Credential>
</To>
```

Some using an email address but some using 8 digits integer.

Answer (score 2):

we take the complete header from the cXMl -

```
<Header> 
<From> 
  <Credential domain="DUNS"> 
    <Identity>cXML-t</Identity> 
  </Credential> 
</From> 
<To> 
  <Credential domain="DUNS"> 
    <Identity>cXML-t</Identity> 
  </Credential> 
</To> 
<Sender> 
  <Credential domain="DUNS"> 
    <Identity>cXML-t</Identity> 
    <SharedSecret>test</SharedSecret> 
  </Credential> 
  <UserAgent>Coupa Procurement 1.0</UserAgent> 
</Sender>
```

1) FROM and To : you can take domain as , NetworkId, DUNS, SAP, whatever your/supplier system allow 
Identity => for ariba, they were provides the Ariba Network Id (ANID) for both buyer and suppliers, other wise put anything , e.g. your name/ company namve also 
2) Sender , Credentials domain  can be  NetworkId, DUNS, SAP, whatever your/supplier system allow 
Identity : email id or user name (which provided by buyer system login)
SharedSecret : passord.

Here, if you are working with Ariba system and the buyer and supplier having the ANID, then they allowed/want to validate and login to the catalog with those other wise using sender credentials as cXML user guide explain.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the DUNS number for the calling customer system in the From and place your DUNS number in the To section.  This is generally used as an identifier within your punchout system that will allow you to identify the user.